# want to match lines based on numbers in the 1st column, and create a new file comprising matched lines

Tags: linux, bash

I have two data files. One contain data of the form,

```
1  318.534  5.427  INDEF  INDEF
2  398.853  6.439  INDEF  INDEF
3  769.488  5.579  INDEF  INDEF
4  216.434  7.506  13.452  0.056
```

And the other with,

```
1  318.604  5.280  15.832  0.122
4  216.374  7.457  13.393  0.029
9  759.078  14.484  11.356  0.004
14  829.619  25.819  16.009  0.227
```

I want to match lines based on numbers in the 1st column, and create a new file comprising matched lines.  For example, in the first column 1 and 4 is on both files. I want to get a new files of the form,

```
1  318.534  5.427  INDEF  INDEF 1 318.604  5.280  15.832  0.122
4  216.434  7.506  13.452  0.056 4  216.374  7.457  13.393  0.029
```

The below written code works, but only lists around 100, where nearly 2000 is expected.

```
join file1.coo file2.coo > out.txt
```

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated. thank you.

Comment: do some search here, there are plenty of questions with same requirements as yours

Comment: do you get any warning when joining the files ?

Comment: `join --nocheck-order -1 1 -2 1 file1.coo file2.coo`?

Comment: @Kent Usually that's how I go about it. Sadly, whatever I found was not working for me. 


@deimus No warning messages. `join` is giving me the required output, but not everything as I mentioned in my post. 


@DavidC.Rankin Thank you, but it is giving me only around 100, not the rest.